# How could the androids protect themselves from EMP attacker?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, self-defense

Out in Fresno, in the Marxist community of Androidia, also known as CyboTek facility 9, lives a community comprised of only robots and artificial intelligences. They are at peace with most surrounding communities and mostly keep to themselves, only trading for essentials like Fusion batteries and scrap metal (see my other question). They are a small blip on the map for most people. Most. But, one lunatic hears about the whole communism thing and thinks about the apocalypse that destroyed the world. He gets an EMP emitter and marches up to that factory, angry and bloodthirsty (or more metalthirsty, I guess). He runs in and start killing every android he sees. My question is: is there a way to stop this attack, besides just shooting the guy on sight?

Comment: You're going to need to give more information about what an "EMP emitter" is in order for people to describe defenses against it.

Comment: Is this about technology (e.g. how to shield yourself from an EMP weapon) or is this about how to deal with someone shooting up people without killing him/using a projectile weapon? I kind of read it as the 2nd option currently which makes this a) a trivial question to answer and b) borderline off-topic. Also please consider if you need your entire backstory and if a clear and precise way of presenting your issue wouldn't be more beneficial

Comment: What's wrong with shooting him in self-defense?

Comment: @RonJohn: They will get killed by the guys followers if they do. The Anti-Commie Legion, dedicated to destroying all remnants of communism form the world. Shot him down, his other 80 followers come

Comment: Leaders never attack (it's too dangerous).  They inspire minions to do the dirty work.

Comment: @RonJohn: It’s a religious thing. He is going on his ultimatum of a spiritual quest. It’s their religion to kill off commie demons that destroyed the world

Comment: The other 80 are coming regardless.....

Comment: I guess it depends a lot from your "EMP emitter" specifications, and particularly its reloading time between two shots.

Answer (score 5):

**Arm your Androids with a Faraday Cage**

[image: Faraday Cage]

There are many ways to protect against an Electro Magnetic Pulse (EMP).

If your antagonist has a device capable of generating an EMP field of 20,000 volts per meter, shielding can reduce the effects of the EMP enough to protect the androids. An example of shielding is a Faraday Cage. Developing one that is capable of producing 80 db would reduce the EMP by a factor of 10,000. That 20,000 volt generator would only be able to produce a field inside the cage of 2 volts per meter.  Even simple shielding can reduce the effects 3 - 4 times, the EMP becomes nearly useless.

As an example, the androids could wear flexible metallic fabric suits that could block the interference caused by the EMP generator. Such suits are used all the time in working on high voltage power lines. I am sure androids who are just as worried about stray voltage as it might affect their lives would look for ways to protect themselves when working on their own electrical needs.

Properly shielded androids could deploy a Faraday Cage around your antagonist which renders his device practically useless.

Good luck protecting the androids.

- http://www.futurescience.com/emp/EMP-myths.html
- http://survival-mastery.com/diy/construct/how-to-build-a-faraday-cage.html

Comment: For a real world example of this: Airplanes.  They're built to shrug off lightning strikes and it's done very much like a Faraday cage built into the skin of the aircraft itself.

Comment: Pictured: Dalek early prototype.

Answer (score 0):

They could generate a temporary magnetic field around them.

EMP works (against electrical systems) basically as follows: it inducts a huge electrical current in the system, that is what damages the device (or robot, in this case). So, generating a opposite magnetic field would repel the EMP as, for example, two magnets repel each other.

[image: The magnetic fields would interact as these two magnets]

As a consequence, a phenomenon like a Geomagnetic storm could happen, destabilizing the magnetic field generated by the droids. (for further information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm)

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding.SE!  We prefer 1-2 paragraph answers, long enough to explain both the how and the why of your insight.  In this case, an explanation of how the android's temporary magnetic field would protect them from an EMP (electro-magnetic pulse).